# openssh-lpk - Failed to get default SELinux security context for ldapuser

Tags: ssh, selinux

I'm trying to setup a ssh server with hardened-gentoo sources openssh (with openssh-lpk, which is the ldap flag on gentoo I think) and selinux enabled.

On the Ldap-Server I have added an user "ldapuser" with a public key. The Login works flawless when selinux is completly disabled.

/etc/selinux/config

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

However when I set selinux is on permissive or enforcing mode the following happens on the client:

```
ssh -v ldapuser@server
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

I see that the public key was accepted.

On the server the only interesting log entry I found was:

```
server sshd[]: error: ssh_selinux_getctxbyname: Failed to get default SELinux security context for ldapuser
```

Which makes sense because this user is on the LDAP Server (but pam_ldap and nsswitch.conf is configured properly to use the ldap server).

All reports I found for this Error, https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325 for example, seem to be closed or not related to my problem.

I'm using Openssh 5.9_p1-r4 with the bindist, hpn, ldap, pam, selinux and tcpd use flags enabled on

```
Linux server 3.7.4-hardened-r1 #2 SMP Fri Feb 8 13:26:25 CET 2013 x86_64 AMD A4-3300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

The question now is:
Is this a bug and I should file a bug report or is it a misconfiguration on my part?
(I wanted to get slowly into selinux with the permissive mode)

Edit:

```
 mediaserv-gentoo ~ # ps -eZ | grep sshd
 kernel                          17017 ?        00:00:01 sshd
 kernel                          25179 ?        00:00:00 sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show output of

> ps -eZ | grep sshd

?

There is two ways of the problem then:

- If it's context is different from system - it just need to be started from right context.
- Alternatively, you just need to create right context for your user.

Comment: Note that this server has selinux disabled because of this issue, so I don't know it the above output actually helps.
Note also that ldapuser is not a user from the system, but a user on the ldap server, so I think there is no context on the system, so the question is how can I specify contexts for external users?